# matlab SVD qustion

Tags: matlab, svd

I have the following Matlab code:

```
r=5;
[U, Gamma, V] = svd( rand(20,10), 'econ' );

L1 = U(:,1:r) * Gamma(1:r,1:r) * V(:,1:r)';

L2 = zeros(20,10); 
for i=1:r
    L2 = L2 + Gamma(i)* U(:,i) * V(:,i)';
end

norm(L1-L2,'fro')
```

Normally, L1 should be the same as L2, and `norm(L1-L2,'fro')` should give zero as the result. However, this is not the case when I type the above commands in a Matlab command window.

Can anyone help me identify the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
L2 = L2 + Gamma(i,i)* U(:,i) * V(:,i)';
```

Comment: Yes, `Gamma` is a diagonal matrix, not a vector. Another fix would be to include the line `Gamma = diag(Gamma);`, then `Gamma(i)` will work as OP expected in the loop.

Comment: Apologies for my mistake!